# Is is possible to run the QGIS python module server side?

Tags: qgis, python, server

I'm pretty new to programming but I want to use the QGIS python module on a server. Basically I am trying to create a JPEG map programatically on a server. I already have a python script to create routes server side I am just trying to find the best way to create a jpeg map with an OSM (or Google) background map, labels, and a legend. QGIS seems like it might be able to do this I am just not sure how difficult or if it's even possible to do on the server using python. I know I could probably do it via Leaflet but since I don't actually need a web map I was hoping QGIS might be a solution. Also it's a Unix server if that matters.

Comment: Have you considered QGIS mapserver (WMS server)?